# Converting project to.net 4.5.1

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, .net-4.5

I am working on a solution which contains multiple projects. it's working on .net version 4.5 and now my PM asked me to convert the solution to .net 4.5.1 and merge it back into the source code. can any one help me how to covert the my current solution into .net 4.5.1

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: @Johnrackwan, are you looking to change target framework for all the projects in the solution ?

Comment: BTW, it's your third question and in the third time it is a duplicate. Please try to use Google first next time and/or read documentation.

Comment: @habib 
yes...can u help me in that, i should successfully complete this task today without any build fails

Comment: @Johnrackwan, you can do that one by one for each project, Right click on project-> properties-> application, Change target framework or use [Target Framework Migrator Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47bded90-80d8-42af-bc35-4736fdd8cd13)

Comment: @habib 
thank you , i will go with Frame Work Migrator

Comment: @habib migration tool worked fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Go into the properties window for each project and change the Target Framework to 4.5.1.